# IFS Formula in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking for a formula in Google Sheet.

The formula is based on an "Imput" sheet and "Output" sheet. In the "Imput" sheet there are following columns:

```
current_position, company_name, current_position_2, current_company_2
```

In the "Output" sheet there are "Title" and "Account name" [Imput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTYht.png) + [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsCHw.png)

The formula should be in "Title" in "Output" and say:

1)

If "current_position" contains "COO", "CEO", "CSO" (and a lot more titles) then take "company_name" and put in "Account Name" under "Output".

2)

If "current_position" does not contain "COO", "CEO", "CSO" (and a lot more titles) AND "current_position_2" contain "COO", "CEO", "CSO" (and a lot more titles) then put "current_position_2" in "Title" in "Output" and "current_company_2" in "Account Name" in "Output"

3)

If neither of "current_position" or "current_position_2 contains "COO", "CEO", "CSO" (and a lot more titles) then take "current_position" and put in "Title" under "Output" and "Current_position_2" and put in "Account Name" in "Output"

Comment: 1)*

If "courrent_position" contains ... than put "current_position" in "Title" and "current_position" in Account Name

Comment: If you share a link to the sheet (being sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor" when you create the link), this would be the most effective and efficient means of getting help. In my mind, this would require one additional sheet/list (to contain all of your preferred titles) and one formula that could then produce all results for the "Output" sheet. I recommend that you manually enter in the "Output" sheet at least one example of each case from your post. BTW, the correct word is "Input" and not "Imput."

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**

As much as possible, make sure to include what you have done so far or share any research you've done to make sure you're [posting a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

**Recommendation:**

On my testing, the IFS Function is quite limited to achieve your goal to set up values to different columns based on multiple conditions.

I have come up with an alternative solution by [creating a custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound#creating_a_bound_script) that checks all values on the 'Imput' sheet and returns the values on 'Output' sheet based on the 3 conditions you've described above:

**UPDATED** **Script:**

```
function onOpen() { // to refresh 
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Output').getRange('C2').setValue("=checkImput()");
}

function checkImput(){
  var imput = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Imput');
  var row = imput.getDataRange().getNumRows();
  var res = [];

  for(var x=2; x<=row; x++){
    var current_position = imput.getRange(x,7).getValue();
    var current_position2 = imput.getRange(x,43).getValue();
    var positions = "COO,CEO,CSO"; //Add new postion separated by comma

    if(positions.includes(current_position)){ // If "courrent_position" contains "COO", "CEO", "CSO" 
      res.push([current_position,imput.getRange(x,8).getValue()]); //Then put "current_position" in "Title" and "current_company" in Account Name
    }else{
      if(positions.includes(current_position2)){ //If "current_position" does not contain "COO", "CEO", "CSO" (and a lot more titles) AND "current_position_2" contain "COO", "CEO", "CSO" 
        res.push([current_position2,imput.getRange(x,44).getValue()]); //Then put "current_position_2" in "Title" in "Output" and "current_company_2" in "Account Name" in "Output"
      }else{ //If neither of "current_position" or "current_position_2 contains "COO", "CEO", "CSO" (and a lot more titles) 
        res.push([current_position2,imput.getRange(x,44).getValue()]); //Then take "current_position" and put in "Title" under "Output" and "Current_position_2" and put in "Account Name" in "Output"
      }
    }
  }
 return res;
}
```

Here's the sample 'Imput' sheet I've tested:

[image]

**Result** on 'Output' sheet:

[image]

Comment: I cant seem to understand why it Says CEO in both Title and Account Name in Row 1. It should say:

Row 2: CEO | Apple
Row 3: CSO | Amazon
Row 4: VP | Facebook

And should i just copy the script into script editor?

Comment: Updated the script. Just copy and paste it. Just make sure the names of your sheets are 'Imput' and 'Output' on your spreadsheet.

Comment: I have added the new script, but "Title" and "Account Name" is still empty on the "Output sheet".

I have tried to create a new spreadsheet and refresh the site but it still doesn't work. I have tried to change the script so where it says "current_position2" it says "current_position_2" so it corresponds to the collum headline.

Am i doing something wrong? Here is a link to the spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lFk-nUzcH7J5XzvvukWWagE0D_PfeXdSkpn0So001sY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I changed the column number on the script based on columns of each data (e.g. current_position is in column 7 on the sheet you've shared) and it will work.

Comment: So how do i change to collum numbers. 

In Imput:

current_position - collum 7
company_name - collum 8
current_position_2 - collum 43
current_company_2 - collum 44

In Output:

Title - Collum 3
Account Name - Collum 4

Comment: Becuase right now when i go in this sheet it doesnt put anything in Title or Account name: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lFk-nUzcH7J5XzvvukWWagE0D_PfeXdSkpn0So001sY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I've updated my script and my answer above. Just remove the old script on your end and paste the new updated script. I've already put the new column number on both of your IMPUT & OUTPUT sheet. The result will be placed to the column C & D (the column of Title & Account on your OUTPUT sheet).

Comment: Thank you so much it works for the 3 rows now. Is it possible to apply the script to x number of rows? If i want to do it for 2000 rows?

Comment: I cant find where it defines the number of rows to apply the script on

Comment: The line on the code var row = imput.getDataRange().getNumRows(); will get all row data on your "Imput" sheet. So if you have 2000 rows of data, it will be processed by the script. But please note that the script will run slower as data gets bigger, it's an expected behavior.